# Small universal monotone Turing machines

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, turing-machines, time-complexity

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2230) surveys small universal Turing machines. What are some examples of small universal *monotone* Turing machines, as described by [Schmidhuber](http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/toesv2/node6.html)? Which of these are efficient (polynomial time) simulators of Turing machines?

> Monotone machines are Turing machines with a one-way read-only input tape, some work tapes, and a one-way write-only output tape. The input tape contains a one-way infinite sequence of 0's and 1's and initially the input head scans the leftmost bit. The output tape is written one symbol at a time, and the output is defined as the finite binary sequence on the output tape if the machine halts, and the possibly infinite sequence appearing on the output tape in a never-ending process if the machine does not halt at all.

From page 276 of *An introduction to Kolmogorov complexity and its applications* by Li and Vitanyi.